# Python Creating a Button class

Tags: python, inheritance, button

Okay I am having some weird problems...I created a Named_Button class

```
class Named_Button(tkinter.Button):
    def __init__(self,name='NoName',master,**k):
            tkinter.Button.__init__(master,**k)
            self.pack()
            self.name = name
 root = Tk()
 Named_Button(root,name='hi',height='4')
 root.mainloop()
```

On trying to create the button I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Named_Button' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try doing this:

```
tkinter.Button.__init__(self, master,**k)
```

Calling the `Button` constructor should probably happen for your subclassed instance, right? And not for the `master` object, whatever that is?

Comment: That wont help at all. I have tkinter being imported as below:
from tkinter import *

Comment: I think it might. Your error messages specifically says that your `Named_Button` instance doesn't have a `tk` attribute. Where should it get it from? The constructor! In your case, the base constructor.